# Convert Joda Date Time String To Java.Sql.TimeStamp for an INSERT

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

Here is my string: 2016-07-29T17:15:46.838Z 
I want to insert this into a MySQL DATETIME(6) column.

Here is the method I created to convert the string to a java.sql.Timestamp

```
private java.sql.Timestamp convertToJavaSqlTimeStamp(String p_dateTimeString) {
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
java.sql.Timestamp _timeStamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(formatter.parseDateTime(p_dateTimeString).getMillis());
return _timeStamp;
}
```

.
.
.

SQL Insert logic...

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement ;
preparedStatement  = _mysqlConn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO myTable (my_date_time) VALUES (?)");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, convertJodaDateTimeStringToJavaSqlTimeStamp("2016-07-29T17:15:46.838Z"));
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Error Message: Invalid format: "2016-07-29T17:15:46.432Z" is malformed at "-07-29T17:15:46.432Z"

Comment: The format you are passing your method appears to be different than the format it expects. I'm not familiar with Java in particular but I would suspect something like this would be more appropriate `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ")` _(with maybe some escapes for the literal T and Z.)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off  Uueerdo's comment. The following did the trick

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

Thank you sir.